# Ruby on Rails - Adding content generated by JavaScript to view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add some graphs generated by my JavaScript(generate_graph.js.erb) to a view.
I am using rails 3.2.1
So in the view I have -

## index.html.erb

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>chart</th>
</tr>

<%= render @stats %>
```

## partial _stat.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= stat.description %></td>
  <td> javascript_fn(stat.data)</td>
</tr>
```

So the questions are
1. Where should I put generate_graph.js.erb
2. How to call this js so as to add the graph to the "td"

Thanks for reading !!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you've made the generate_graph file a .js.erb instead of just .js?

If it will work as a regular js file, put it in app/assets/javascripts.

Then just do something like:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= stat.description %></td>
    <td>
        <script>
           javascript_fn(<%= stat.data %>);
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I know some people prefer not to have inline javascript, but sometimes it's just easier, imo.

Comment: Thanks for replying @theButler. I realised that .js.erb was wrong, so I added the javascript at the top of my index.html.erb. This worked for me but I am in favour of moving it out of the index page. I will try your suggestion. Thanks again